# Partition drive E for install Fedora and keep Windows in the SSD

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, mbr, gpt

Take a look to the following partition table that my PC have. For me this is a mess. Right now I want to use `E` drive and create two partition and I can't because is marked as MBR and also is the primary partition. I am using EaseUS Partition Master Professional for operate over partition system.

[image: Windows 10 current partition]

Having the picture above I have the following questions:

- Why if I have Windows installed on Disk2 (GPT) the primary partition is `E`?
- Is there any way to fix it without reinstall the OS?
- If I reinstall how do I avoid the same behavior?
- Is something wrong in the connectors at motherboard and I am not seeing that and because of that is this wrong setup? (my MB is [MSI Z97-GAMING5](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/Z97-GAMING-5.html#hero-specification))

The only disk I can't touch is `D` since this one is holding all my information that can not be erased.

I can think in the easy solution, disconnect the D and E drives from the MB and install Windows on the SSD then connect them back and partition E for install Fedora but this will be the ugly solution I believe, don't you think?

I need ideas, advice, help so any?